# materializecss append multiple select forms

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have problem with appending multiple select forms..

Because materializecss using jquery selectForm and if I append new select form then it doesn't show.

https:// codepen.io/anon/pen/omBjNq

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#product_field').append('<div class="row"><div class="input-field col s2"><select><option>Select 1</option><option>Select 2</option><option>Select 3</option><option>Select 4</option></select></div><div class="input-field col s1 right"><button name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">-</button></div></div>');
                 $('select').trigger('contentChanged').formSelect();
            });

            $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
            });


            $('select').formSelect();
              $('select').on('contentChanged', function() {
              $(this).formSelect();
        });
});
```

Simply remove the tr and td from your html string and you forgot to call the formSelect() after appending a new select

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the structure of the html with this modification it will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#product_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><div class="row"><div class="input-field col s2"><select><option>Select 1</option><option>Select 2</option><option>Select 3</option><option>Select 4</option></select></div><div class="input-field col s1 right"><button name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">-</button></div></div></td></tr>');
             $("#row"+i+" select").formSelect();
        });

        $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
             $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
        });


        $('select').formSelect();
    });
```

The only change was, when I created a new ´tr´, at that moment create a new instance of ´formSelect´.